# How to use count and order by with inner join in mysql?

Tags: sql

[employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwuBQ.png)

[department table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztGqO.png)

How to display department name and number of employees working for that department.

My SQL code:

```
SELECT department.dname , employee.count(*)
FROM employee
INNER JOIN department
ON dno=dnumber
ORDER BY department.dname;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
select d.dname, count(*)
from employee e inner join
     department d
     on d.dno = e.dnumber
group by d.dname
order by d.dname;
```

Notes:

- You are describing an aggregation query with one row per department.  That suggests `GROUP BY`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names.  I have to guess what table `dno` comes from.  There should be no reason to guess.

Comment: how to write Query for this:-  Display employee name and employee number of employees who work in the  same department as ‘JOYCE’ work. Display employees other than ‘JOYCE’